# Node-Webkit: What authentication method should I use to authenticate user from google account

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, node-webkit, google-authentication

I am creating an application with `node-webkit`

In my index.html I have provided an option to user to login with `google account`

**Problem**

What redirect URI will I give while making `client secret`?

As you can see the `NS js` application runs directly from there location which means that that URL is always different.
[image]